# Is it possible to use iframe with localhost address in source ?

Tags: asp.net, html, browser

My HTML markup is pretty simple

```
....
<iframe width="800" height="800" src="http://localhost:69345/Handler.ashx"/>
...
```

but this page is blocked by all browser that I've used.
I'm wondering is there any workaround for this issue?
Surely, I completely understand that in case when my page will be deployed in production there will be no problems. However, **how can I do any testing if iframe is blocked on local?**

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Is the port number for the iframe the same as the main site?  If so you should use a root relative url "/Handler.ashx".  Also, are you running the web server on the same computer you are testing?  localhost for an iframe will only work in that scenario, so if you're connecting to a dev box from another computer it will break.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Don't use absolute url*

**use relative**

```
....
<iframe width="800" height="800" src="Handler.ashx"/>
...
```

Comment: Of course i'm using relative url. I changed it only for example, but in don't work either.

Comment: What if the page containing the iFrame is from another domain?

Comment: @Disposer are you trying to use iframe from a different domain?

Comment: @YiğitYener: not possible due to `same origin policy` .http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: @Champ SOP doesn't block iframes

Comment: @Disposer can you give the Url of the main page in which you are trying to use this iframe?

Comment: @Disposer You either copied and pasted on haste or you don't understand what localhost is

Comment: @Disposer if the `Default.aspx` and  `Handler.ashx` are in the same directory structure then it should work with no problem

Answer (score 10):

When Chrome shows the following text in the iframe:

[image: 127.0 0.1 refused to connect]

It's because the server responded with the [`X-Frame-Options` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) to `DENY`.

The solution is to change the server configuration so that it removes this header or sets it to `SAMEORIGIN`.

For example, if you're using a Django, you can either change the [`X_FRAME_OPTIONS` setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/clickjacking/#setting-x-frame-options-for-all-responses) or decorate your view with [`@xframe_options_sameorigin` or `@xframe_options_exempt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/clickjacking/#setting-x-frame-options-per-view).

Answer (score 5):

Try using your machine's actual IP address (typically 127.0.0.1)...

```
<iframe width="800" height="800" src="http://127.0.0.1:69345/Handler.ashx"/>
```

Don't forget the port number!

P.S: On Mac OS you can run something like `ifconfig | grep inet` or `ifconfig | grep 127` to identify your network IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try with relative path

```
<iframe width="800" height="800" src="Handler.ashx"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems here. The first is that the request is expecting to be served on port 69345 (which looks very much like a port auto-configured by the debugger). Is that port currently serving requests? Can you go to that page without the iframe? When the page is deployed in production, this url is absolutely guaranteed to break because localhost always resolves to 127.0.0.1 which is relative to the client, not the server. You need to review what the actual address is or will need to be. As some posters have answered while I type this, your problem may be as simple as using a relative url. If that does not address your issue, you will need to investigate the actual ports and server names that will be serving this handler.

Comment: Without iframe page works well, furthermore page displays correctly except iframe that is blocked by browser. I've used IE, FF, Chrome

Comment: @Disposer You misread the advice I think.  Does going to `http://localhost:69345/Handler.ashx` work properly for you?

Comment: @Matt Whipple Unfortunately not. I've got the iframe blocked

Comment: @Disposer Outside of the iframe: you should be able to go directly to that address, no iframe involved. If you can't then the problem is that page and has nothing to do with iframes at all.